# Spotify API returning with 404 error

Tags: javascript, authentication, spotify

I'm trying to access the Spotify API using only client-side JavaScript. According to their [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) I need to use the "implicit-grant" flow. The first step is to send users from [my React app](https://nydame-bloc-jams-v2.netlify.com/) to an API endpoint at spotify.com; here is an example of I'm using: `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dtoken%26scope%3Duser-read-private%20user-read-email%26client_id%3Dae45a76e6e264417a49a32043284912b%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fnydame-bloc-jams-v2.netlify.com%2Flibrary&state=a54hm27jfk`.

I don't understand how I can get a 404 error when I'm using the correct endpoint URL (yes, I checked for spelling errors!) but here's a hint, maybe: the 404 page shows the following security-related errors in web inspector:

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: ;(function installGlobalHook(window) {
 ....`

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: !function(t){function __webpack_require_....`

and

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-5784146-31&cid=1787973498.1522278426&jid=1945824252&_v=j66&z=514970388 (“img-src”).`

Comment: You need to set up your server such that those desired external resources can be requested - it's not an issue with Spotify.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extremely fast feedback! I will change my focus accordingly.